# Track By in ng-repeat throwing "Token 'track' is an unexpected token"

Tags: angularjs

I've a simple `ng-repeat` with `track by` expression which wont work.
Here's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0pL9wr6/1/).

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5] track by $index">
    {{n}}
</div>
```

Resulting **Token 'track' is an unexpected token at column 19 of the expression [[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5] track by $index] starting at [track by $index].**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're using Angular version 1.0.3 in the fiddle.

Change your version to (minimum of) 1.2 and it will work, since it was introduced in that version.

I'll provide the fiddle in a comment since there's no code.